# Eclipselink Discriminator Column Returns NULL

Tags: java, eclipselink, discriminator

This question is around JPA and Discriminators.

Motivation: I am implementing a system with various fields which will required some domain values. For example, types for fields (Gender Type: Male and Female; ID Type: Drivers License; Avenue Type and so on...).

Since my system is metadata driven, I won't be creating these attributes as ENUM. I need them in an easy to fetch place.

In order to do that, I created a parent abstract class labeled ALNDOMAIN (Alpha Numeric Domains). And all the inherited classes are going to be part of my objects (for example, IDType extends ALNDomain).

The issue: my system is going to have around 200 ALNDomains subclasses. I don't want to create one repository for every subclass. I would prefer to have a single repository in the ALNDomain class and fetch the Discriminator Value. Everytime I fetch my Domain, the discriminator columns is coming as NULL:

```js
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="ALNNAME", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class ALNDomain {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;
 
 @Column(name="ALNNAME", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
 private String alnname;
 private String value;
 private String description;
 
 public long getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public String getValue() {
  return value;
 }
 public void setValue(String value) {
  this.value = value;
 }
 public String getDescription() {
  return description;
 }
 public void setDescription(String description) {
  this.description = description;
 }
 public String getAlnname() {
  return alnname;
 }
 public void setAlnname(String alnname) {
  this.alnname = alnname;
 }
}
```

That's the subclass:

```js
package com.ang.entity.core;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import com.ang.entity.base.domains.ALNDomain;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("IDTYPE")
public class IDType extends ALNDomain {

}
```

That's my repository:

```js
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "alndomain", path = "alndomain")
@CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600)
public interface ALNDomainRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ALNDomain, Long>{
 List<ALNDomain> findByAlnname(@Param("alnname") String alnname);
}
```

When I access my repository, the discriminator column is null. That's the result:

```js
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "iDTypes" : [ {
      **"alnname" : null,**
      "value" : "RG",
      "description" : "Registro Nacional",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/iDType/1"
        },
        "iDType" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/iDType/1"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
```

ALNNAME shouldn't be null. I would need it to avoid creating 200 repositories to access all the list of possible values for each type of ALNDOMAIN.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: How are you inserting the subclass, and what is the alnname value when you call persist?  If it isn't set when you call persist, it won't be set when you next access it, unless you force the property to be reloaded/refreshed from the database.  Caching will keep that instance in memory.

Comment: Hi Chris,

    I am not setting ALNName since it is a column that should be automatically populated by the discriminator value:
    @DiscriminatorValue("IDTYPE")

    Should I manually set the ALNName? Or should it be automatically set?

   Also observe that I am following the recommendation to set ALNName as insertable = false, updatable=false since it should be managed by the JPA and not manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your entities have two mappings to the "ALNNAME" column -

1. The class type as specified with the @DiscriminatorColumn and
   @DiscriminatorValue annotations.
2. The alnname property marked readonly through the @Column settings.

These two mappings are completely independent of each other, and have no linking in JPA.  So while the alnname will be set if the entity is loaded from the database, it will not ever be set by JPA until then.

This property is pretty much completely redundant though with JPA supporting the TYPE function in queries, and Java instances being able to get the class name.  If you must keep this property stored in your entity, you are better off setting it when you create a new instance of a subclass, or instead, override the get method on subclasses to return the desired string instead.  There is no way to change the value on an instance - java doesn't allow you to morph an object from one class to another, so it isn't possible in JPA without creating an entirely new instance either.

Comment: Ok Chris, thanks for you valuable feedback. Based on this, I found an alternative way to instanciate a Spring Repository dinamically. Basically I am doing "new SimpleJpaRepository<ALNDomain, Long>(domainClass,em)" where domainClass is a dynamic class loaded based on my metamodel.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found around that was to dinamically instantiate a Repository based on the Class type since I am in the Server.

Basically I replaced my method:
List findByAlnname(@Param("alnname") String domainClassName)

to execute the following:

```
        Class domainClass;
        try {
            domainClass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(domainClassName);
            if (domainClass!=null && ALNDomain.class.isAssignableFrom(domainClass)) {

                SimpleJpaRepository<ALNDomain, Long> jpaRep = new SimpleJpaRepository<ALNDomain, Long>(domainClass,em);

                return jpaRep.findAll();
            }   
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```